# Firefox extension: chrome.system is undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am converting a Chrome extension to Firefox.  One bump I've hit is trying to use [`chrome.system.display`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_display)

It's required as `system.display` in the manifest permissions in Chrome, but produces a warning in Firefox.  Ignoring the warning and running the extension results in:

> chrome.system is undefined

Is there some equivalent way to get display info (screen size, number of screens) in a Firefox extension?

Comment: I thought in firefox you use `browser.` instead of `chrome.`

Comment: Both namespaces are supported in Firefox.  I tested browser.system and get the same result.

Comment: OK, didn't realise firefox did that - there's no documentation on MDN regarding *system.display* - so, at a guess, it's something chrome have that firefox hasn't yet duplicated

Comment: Firefox WebExtensions are a different thing and there's a [separate documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API) that doesn't list `system` API which means it's not implemented. There's no alternative. You can use the standard methods like `window.screen` for some parts.

Comment: wOxxOm is right. Plus, to avoid warnings like this in Firefox you have to manipulate your manifest.json in a build script.